# understanding the solution of a given Lebesgue integration.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, proof-writing, lebesgue-integral

The question and its solution are given below:

> [image]
>   [image]

**My questions are:**

I am supposed to calculate the Lebesgue integration of the function $f$ on the interval $[0, \pi/2]$, why the solution divides the interval $[0, \pi/2]$ into what is shown in the picture? depending on what theorem? I am suspecting if this solution is correct, could anyone tell me the correct solution?

Thanks!

Comment: Your approach completely misunderstands the problem. $\Bbb Q$ is the set of all rational numbers. How did you mistake it for the intervals $[0,\pi/6] \cup [\pi/4,\pi/2]$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that your solution is not correct.

You must use the fact that the integral of  each integrable function $f$ on a set of measure equal to $0$ is $0$.

But $m(cos^{-1}(\mathbb{Q}))=0$, so

$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}}fdx =\int_{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\cap cos^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})}fdx + \int_{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\cap cos^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})^c}fdx =$

$=0+ \int_{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\cap cos^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})^c}fdx=$

$= \int_{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\cap cos^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})^c}sin^2(x)dx=$

$= \int_{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\cap cos^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})}sin^2(x)dx + \int_{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]\cap cos^{-1}(\mathbb{Q})^c}sin^2(x)dx=$

$= \int_{[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]}sin^2(x)dx$

Now you can compute this integral because the function $sin^2(x)$ is smooth and the domain of integration is an interval,  so the Lebesgue integral is the Riemann integral.

Comment: but in case one  $\cos (x) \in \mathbb{Q}$ not the $x \in \mathbb{Q}$?

Comment: @Smart thanks you very much

Answer (score 4):

Your solution is not correct. Since $$m\{x\mid \cos(x)\in \mathbb Q\}=0,$$
you have $$\int_0^{\pi/2}f(x)\,\mathrm d x=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2(x)\,\mathrm d x.$$

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach: $\cos x$ takes any particular value only in a countbale set. Hence $\{x: \cos x \in \mathbb Q\}$ is a countable set. But countable sets have measure $0$. Hence the given integral is same as $\int_0^{\pi /2} \sin^{2}x dx=\frac {\pi} 4$.

Comment: is this because the integration of $- \cos(x)$  is $\sin (x)$ ..... so we are always trying to change any Lebesgue integration to Riemann integration?